# What are these yellowish/white bumps on my cooked bacon?

Tags: meat, fat, mold, bacon, breakfast

This bacon was expired by 1 day, I smelled it and made sure it didn’t look weird before cooking it. After I cooked the bacon I noticed these yellowish bumps on some of the pieces. Is it mold? Is it fat? [image]

Comment: If the bacon was sealed when you opened it and kept refrigerated, chances are it was still fairly safe 1 day after the expiration date. Did these yellowish bumps exist before you cooked the bacon? Can you scrape off the yellowish bumps? Try smelling/tasting while ready to spit out whatever you've tasted if it has an off smell or taste. Your sense smell and taste should provide you with enough information to make a decision.